# Silverlight Find Control in Data Template

Tags: xaml, silverlight, controltemplate

I have the following xaml code:

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem Name="btnPrev" Cursor="Hand" ItemClick="btnPrev_ItemClick">
<dxb:BarButtonItem.ContentTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Image x:Name="imgSkipLeft" Source="/ProjectTool;component/images/arrowleft.png" Height="16" Width="16">
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtBlockTip_Left"/>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Image>
</DataTemplate>
</dxb:BarButtonItem.ContentTemplate>
</dxb:BarButtonItem>
```

How can I find txtBlockTip_Left and modify the text

Answer (score 0):

Rather that trying to find the TextBlock on the DataTemplate to change the text it would be better to set the text through a binding and then change the property that the Text property is bound to.  The following resource has an example on how to use data binding within a DataTemplate: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/binding/data-binding-to-controls-%28silverlight-quickstart%29

Answer (score 0):

Using the VisualTreeHelperExtensions class and put a grid inside the data template and give it a name, in the example below the name is grdTemplate.

```
var bttn= btnPrev.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(btnPrev);
var dataTemplate = bttn.GetDescendantsOfType<Grid>().FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == ("grdTemplate"));
var textBlocks= VisualTreeHelperExtensions.GetDescendantsOfType<TextBlock>(dataTemplate);
TextBlock txtBlockTip_left = textBlocks.ElementAt(0);
```